# Table containing TEXT column growing continuously

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We've got a table in a production system which (for legacy reasons) is running SQL 2005 (9.0.5266) and contains a TEXT column (along with a few other columns of various datatypes).

All of a sudden (since a week ago) we noticed the size of this one table increasing linearly by 10-15GB per day (whereas previously it has always remained at a constant size).  The table is a queue for a messaging system, and as such the data in it completely refreshes itself every few seconds.  At any one time there could be anywhere from 0 to around 1000 rows, but it fluctuates rapidly as messages are inserted, and sent (at which point they're deleted).

We can't find anything that was changed on the day the growth started - so have no obvious potential cause identified at this stage.

One "obvious" culprit is the TEXT column, and so we checked to see if any massive values were now being stored, but (using DATALENGTH) we found no single rows above around ~32k. We've run CHECKDB, updated space usage, rebuild all indexes, etc - nothing reduces the size (and CHECKDB showed no errors).

We've queried sys.allocation_units and the size increase is definitely LOB_DATA (which show total_pages and used_pages increasing together at a constant rate).

To reduce the database size last night we simple created a new table along-side the one in question (which is luckily referenced via a view by the application), dropped the old table, and renamed the new one.  We left last night, taking comfort in the fact that we'd alleviated the space issues, and that we had a backup of the dodgy table to investigate further today.
However, this morning the table size is already up to 14GB (and growing), while there are only the usual ~500 rows in the table, and MAX(DATALENGTH(text_column)) is only showing around 35k.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this "runaway" growth, or anything else that we could try or query to get more information about what exactly is using the space?

Cheers, 
Dave

Comment: Have you checked for ghost records via sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats?

Comment: Are you running SQL Server Full-Text services?  Have you checked if you can "shrink" the DB (SSMS, right-click the DB, Tasks, Shrink, DB)?  Is the percent free space above 5%?

Comment: Thanks Robert - there are zero ghost records. And no, we can't shrink the data file, tgolisch - the space is actually "in use" - when you say "free space" are you referring to the data file or drive?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add; no, we're not running fulltext on this database.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but is the table a heap? Also, the app shouldn't care if you change the data type to VARCHAR(MAX), have you considered that?

Comment: How many pages did sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats show it consuming? How many are LOB pages and how many are in row data? Has anyone added additional indexes to the table?

Comment: No changes to the table (adding indexes, etc). Currently the LOB pages are at 1701984 (IN_ROW data totals around 45000 pages). Hi Aaron; no, table is not a heap. Changing to VARCHAR(MAX) has now been added to the top of our "to-do list" - but the last time we tried that (several years ago) there was an issue with the application and we had to roll back (I can't quite remember what it was now though...).

Comment: That's not adding up. 1701984 LOB pages = 13615872K / 500 rows = 27231.744K = 26.5935 GB average per row. No way to get that average with 500 rows and a max size of 32K. Can you share the ouput of sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats for that table (index id 0 or 1)?

Comment: Tell me about it. ;) I've posted a screenshot of a few queries here: http://twitpic.com/ajvrot

Comment: sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats does not check for ghost records when run in limited mode. It always returns null for that column and for version ghost records as well. Please run it in detailed mode. Also, do you ever truncate this table?

Comment: Aah, true. My bad. We since figured it must be ghost records, but only because we restored a backup of the database to a non-prod server and ran a dbcc forceghostcleanup, and it reduced the table size (after a running for a while).  We don't truncate that table (it gets thousands of inserts a minute, so the risk of losing rows is too high - although we do know that truncating the table does reduce the table size instantly.  One of the guys in my team found reference to someone with a similar issue, and they said a service restart fixed it, so might try that tonight.

Comment: The reason for asking about Truncate was because of the possibility of deferred drops. When you truncate a large table, it doesn't drop the empty pages right away. They are marked to be dropped and then got actually dropped by a background task. This makes Truncate run faster.

Comment: I'm not sure a restart will fix the ghost record issue. The problem is that ghost records have to first be detected before they can be cleaned up. Detection requires reading the particular page again. If you have pages with nothing but ghost records on them, then you will not read those pages again and they won't get marked for cleanup. If this becomes a regular issue, you may want to consider setting up a maintenance job to clear it up on a recurring basis.

Comment: We've got a few things lined up for this weekend, so I'll update next week with whether we managed to fix the issue or not. Thanks again Robert.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem in [dealing with queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/09/dealing-with-large-queues/). The article linked talks about Service Broker queues, but the issue is the same for ordinary tables used as queues. If you have a busy system with generous resources (CPU, memory, disk IO) and you push a queue on this system to high throughput, then a large portion of these resources will be used to handle the two operations: enqueue (ie. INSERT) and dequeue (ie. DELETE). However, the full lifecycle of the record requires *three* operations: INSERT, DELETE and ghost purge. They cost roughly the same in terms on CPU/memory/disk IO needs, so if you use that queue for say 90% of the system resources then you should allocate 30% resources to each. But only the first two are under your control (ie. explicit statements running in user sessions). The third one, the ghost purge, is a background process controlled by SQL Server, and there is no chance the ghost cleanup process will be allowed to consume 30% resources. This is a fundamental issue and, if you push the pedal-to-the-metal for long enough time your **will* hit it. Once ghost records accumulate and pass system/workload specific threshold the performance will degrade quickly and the symptoms will spiral to abysmal performance (a negative feedback loop forms).

Luckily, since you do not use Service Broker queues but real tables as queues, you have some better tools at your disposal, like `ALTER TABLE REORGANIZE` and `ALTER TABLE REBUILD`. By far the best solution is an online index/table rebuild. SQL Server 2012 supports [online operations on tables containing BLOBs](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/) and you can eleverage that. Of course you would have to get rid of the deprecated obsolete `TEXT` type and use `VARCHAR(MAX)`, but that goes w/o saying.

As a side note:

> If you have pages with nothing but ghost records on them, then you
>   will not read those pages again and they won't get marked for cleanup

This is incorrect. Pages with nothing but ghosts will be detected and purged by scans. As I said, the issue is not detection, is resources. If you push your system enough, you will race ahead of the ghost cleanup and he will never catch up.

Comment: Thanks Remus, we're busy doing additional diagnosis so I will come back to this post in the next few days with what we find (if anything).

Answer (score 0):

Early this morning I restarted the SQL service on the instance with this "problem queue table".  It appears that this has fixed the issue.  Immediately following the restart, I monitored the LOB_DATA page-in-use count, and it started dropping straight away.  It was being cleaned up quite slowly, so probably took around an hour or two to reclaim the 60+GB of space being held (I went to bed after I'd made sure all was well).

At the moment the table is back to normal as far as in-use allocations (hovering around <100 pages), and is not showing any signs of re-growing.

Given the fact that we have used this table in the same way (i.e. as a queue) for at least 10 years, and it has had busier periods than what we've had over the past week or two, I would've been surprised if it was the issue described by Remus above (although I understand how that can occur; I guess this specific queue just isn't quite busy enough to swamp the ghost cleanup process?).  Very strange...

Thanks again for the help guys!